# CSS: Automatic page breaks?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to automatically detect when content encroaches upon a page margin and then force a page break with CSS? I have a DIV that has a border and some content:

```
<div id="container">
   This content could spill into the bottom margin of the printed page....
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Is there a `@print` rule that would do the following:

```
+----------+
|          |
|  page 1  |
|          |
| content  |
|          |
| this over|
+----------+

+----------+
|flows and |
|the CSS   |
|makes a   |
|new page  |
|with a    |
|border    |
+----------+
```

I'd like to avoid having to write rules that manually force breaks, if possible, and a good solution should go (all the way) back to IE8/older Firefoxes. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Googling this? http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

Comment: Yes, I landed there already. He seems to manually force page breaks with .page-break class selectors, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to split a div to achieve that. One way would be to break inside elements, such as paragraphs.

For example:

```
<div id="print">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>

#print {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

@media print {
    #print {
        border: 0;
    }

    #print p {
        border: 2px solid #000;
    }

    #print p:last-child {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
}
```

The desktop version would create something like this:

```
+-----------+
|           |
|  page 1   |
|           |
| content   |
|           |
|with border|
+-----------+
```

Print version would be:

```
+-----------+
|           |
|  page 1   |
|           |
| content   |
|           |
|with border|
+-----------+

+-----------+
|           |
|  page 2   |
|           |
| content   |
|           |
|with border|
+-----------+
```